# отображение заболеваний по областям России в leaflet Rstudio

Tags: веб-программирование, клиент-сервер, r, leafletjs, shiny

Я пыталась сделать в RStudio с пакетом leaflet и shiny такое же интерактивное отображение на карте количества заболеваний по России. [image: карта]

Мои данные выглядят следующим образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
rval_mass_shootings <- reactive({
covid %>% 
  filter(
    дата >= input$date_range[1],
    дата <= input$date_range[2],
    заболевания >= input$n_заболевания
   )
})
 output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
 rval_mass_shootings() %>%
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView( 98.58, 39.82, zoom = 5) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    radius = ~ заболевания,
    fillColor = 'red', color = 'red', weight = 1
    )
 })
 }
```

Клиент:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
theme = shinythemes::shinytheme('simplex'),
leaflet::leafletOutput('map', height = '100%', width = '100%'),
absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10, id = 'controls',
            sliderInput('n_заболевания', 'Min заболеваний', 1, 200, 10),
            dateRangeInput('date_range', 'Дата', "2020-03-30", "2020-05-30")
),
tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

И ошибка при запуске приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, как привязать области к карте (может проблема в моих данных и названиях областей на русском?) и как заставить это все работать :((((
Буду благодарна за любые решения или советы!

Comment: очень интересный вопрос! вы смогли его решить?